# When I'm delivering a page with the XHTML mime type, should I use XML DOM or HTML DOM?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

I prefer using the XHTML mime type for pages, instead of HTML, and serve a different mime type to IE, but when I do this, should I use XML DOM or HTML DOM?

Comment: Either you build your page as XHTML or as HTML, you should not choose the mime type independent of the structure of your page. What do you mean with XML/HTML DOM? With the DOM you can access certain elements (nodes) in a document, it is not something different for XHTML and HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean DOCTYPE or do you really mean mime type? And, why do you prefer sending html to IE and xhtml to everyone else? Seems like an unnecessary complication.

As a side note, why would anyone whose audience is the general public prefer serving XHTML over HTML? I should probably ask that in another thread if I really want an answer...